# How can I get my checkboxes to enable/disable onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get checkboxes, in this case titled "Male" and "Female" to allow one option to be chosen. Ie, click male, female checkbox gets grayed out/disabled, uncheck male, female checkbox re-enables and is able to clicked which would subsequently disabled the male checkbox option.

I have been able to check either box and get the other to disable using "onClick" inline. However once the other checkbox disables, when I uncheck the chosen box it stays disabled.

```
                          <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" onClick="hideFemaleCheckBox()" value="male" id="maleCheckBox">
                                Male
                          </label>
     <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"  onClick="hideMaleCheckBox()" value="female" id="femaleCheckBox">
                                Female<br><br>
                             </label>
```

..

```
        function hideFemaleCheckBox() {
              let maleCheckBox = document.getElementById('maleCheckBox');
              let femaleCheckBox = document.getElementById('femaleCheckBox');
              if(maleCheckBox.checked == true) {
                    femaleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
              } else if (maleCheckBox.checked == false) {
                    femaleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "false");     
              }
              
        }

        function hideMaleCheckBox() {
              let maleCheckBox = document.getElementById('maleCheckBox');
              let femaleCheckBox = document.getElementById('femaleCheckBox');
              if(femaleCheckBox.checked == true) {
                    maleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
              } else if (femaleCheckBox.checked == false) {
                    maleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "false");     
              }
              
        }
```

Any help to get this working would be appreciated. I am still learning, thank you!

Comment: Why not using a radio button, I think it fits better for this purpose

Comment: Is there a reason for not using radio buttons in a name set?

Comment: I have considered that and it is an option I suppose. The full context of this is that it is a medical form that has several checkboxes that would require this type of rule to be applied. If anything I of course can swap to radio buttons and try that way. At this point my big thing is that I am positive what I am trying to achieve can be done and I just don't know how. Now its a knowledge mission as well.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle

Comment: If you use two radio buttons instead of checkboxes and give them the same name, HTML will allow to select only one of them without the need of hiding them. Change both types to `radio` and add them a `name='gender'` to see it. Only one radio button in a group (group means same name value) can be selected at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the disabled attribute on Female once the user unchecked male checkbox.
See below:

```
function hideFemaleCheckBox() {
  let maleCheckBox = document.getElementById("maleCheckBox");
  let femaleCheckBox = document.getElementById("femaleCheckBox");
  if (maleCheckBox.checked == true) {
    femaleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  } else if (maleCheckBox.checked == false) {
    // change here | Use removeAttribute
    femaleCheckBox.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}

function hideMaleCheckBox() {
  let maleCheckBox = document.getElementById("maleCheckBox");
  let femaleCheckBox = document.getElementById("femaleCheckBox");
  if (femaleCheckBox.checked == true) {
    maleCheckBox.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  } else if (femaleCheckBox.checked == false) {
    // change here | Use removeAttribute
    maleCheckBox.removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}
```

Use removeAttribute function to remove the disabled property.